# Как создать гиперссылку в новом столбце DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

Есть DataFrame с двумя столбцами: заголовком статьи и ссылкой на нее.

Как можно получить третий столбец, где текстом будет заголовок статьи, но будет иметь гиперссылку на статью?

Comment: `<a href="ссылка">заголовок статьи</a>`?

Comment: [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Answer (score 5):

Пусть `df` такое:

> ```
>               name               link
> 0  Total Commander    www.ghisler.com
> 1           Pandas  pandas.pydata.org
> ```

**Команда:**

```
df["hypertext"] = '<a href="' + df.link + '">' + df.name + '</a>'
```

---

*Результат:*

> ```
>               name               link                                     hypertext
> 0  Total Commander    www.ghisler.com  <a href="www.ghisler.com">Total Commander</a>
> 1           Pandas  pandas.pydata.org         <a href="pandas.pydata.org">Pandas</a>
> ```

---

*Примечание:*

Теперь, когда вы хотите изобразить таблицу с работающими гиперссылками в Jupyter Notebook, напишите

```
from IPython.display import HTML
HTML(df.to_html(escape=False))
```

как можете видеть и с тем, что вы получите:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Или можете сделать

```
print(df.to_html(escape=False))
```

получая HTML код:

```html
<table border="1" class="dataframe">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">
      <th></th>
      <th>name</th>
      <th>link</th>
      <th>hypertext</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>0</th>
      <td>Total Commander</td>
      <td>www.ghisler.com</td>
      <td><a href="www.ghisler.com">Total Commander</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>1</th>
      <td>Pandas</td>
      <td>pandas.pydata.org</td>
      <td><a href="pandas.pydata.org">Pandas</a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

который вы можете прямо запустить (клик на «Выполнить код» выше) или вставить в ваш HTML файл.

Comment: У `<a>` используется атрибут `href`, а не `link`: http://htmlbook.ru/html/a :) Плюс, нехватает кавычек, думаю, что присутствие желательно :) т.е. что-то вроде такого: `f'<a href="{df.link}">{df.name}</a>'`

Comment: @gil9red - спасибо вам, исправил.

Answer (score 5):

Пример данных позаимствован у [@MarianD](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1135728):

```
df["hypertext"] = df["link"].map('<a href="{}">'.format) + df["name"] + "</a>"
```

---

Результат:

```
In [130]: df
Out[130]:
              name               link                                      hypertext
0  Total Commander    www.ghisler.com  <a href="www.ghisler.com">Total Commander</a>
1           Pandas  pandas.pydata.org         <a href="pandas.pydata.org">Pandas</a>
```